# Depth of Sidebar Table of Contents in LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm working with the `Goettingen` LaTeX beamer theme, which has a sidebar with table of contents. The toc shows sections and subsection, but I would like to only show the sections in this table of contents. Usually I would do this by setting the `tocdepth` counter

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

But this has not effect on the sidebar toc. Is there some other counter or simple way of changing the tocdepth for the sidebar?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Requirements}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Req 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Req 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Req 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Preliminaries}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Thing 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Thing 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Care to give a MWE?

Comment: try `\documentclass[hideallsubsections]{beamer}`

Comment: `\documentclass[hideallsubsections]{beamer}` is the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer has an option to hide subsections from the ToC, the sidebar etc.

```
\documentclass[hideallsubsections]{beamer}
```